# scrollToFocus to cell with enableCellEditOnFocus=true does not make the cell editable

Tags: angular-ui-grid

In the version 3.0.0-rc.21 of angular-ui-grid calls to scrollToFocus() to a cell in a grid with enableCellEditOnFocus set to true would move the cursor to that cell and it would be immediately editable. In version 3.0.7 this no longer works in certain cases (see below).

I call the scrollToFocus() after a navigate (tab) event. It checks the values of certain cells and will jump the user to the next line based on a certain condition. However, if the cell that the user would have tabbed to without the scrollToFocus() is editable, then I think it sends an endEdit event and the cell the user has the focus on is no longer editable.

If the cell that the user would have tabbed to is not editable, the scrollToFocus() works fine.

Please see the Plunker which has instructions on how to prove the issue. http://plnkr.co/edit/bV9CYdHEEksvRtFUglhr?p=preview

Basically, this line shows the issue

```
{ name: 'name2', displayName: 'Name2 (editable)', width: '20%', enableCellEdit: true },
```

If the line is like this, all works fine

```
{ name: 'name2', displayName: 'Name2 (editable)', width: '20%', enableCellEdit: false },
```

Comment: To me it's working correctly, can you reproduce behaviour in a plunkr?

Comment: I started developing the plunker and you're right, it still works. So, there is something else in my (fairly complex) grid that is interfering with the editability (and that didn't do so in RC 21). Working on that now...

Comment: I figured it out and will edit the question

Comment: When I first asked the question, I thought it was an implementation issue, now I think it might be a bug, so I've raised it on the grid GitHub site. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/4812