# Angular UI Grid set focus to cell on navigate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have a grid which is editable. Two of the columns are ItemCode and Quantity. When a user enters a Quantity and presses the down key, I would like the next row to set the focus on the ItemCode cell for the next row. I added this event listener and it goes to the cell, but it quickly flashes into edit mode, then out into selected mode. How can I make sure the cell stays in edit mode?

```
gridApi.cellNav.on.navigate($scope, function (newRowcol, oldRowCol) {
    $scope.$broadcast('uiGridEventEndCellEdit');

    if (oldRowCol != null && 
        oldRowCol.col.colDef.name == 'quantity' && 
        oldRowCol.row != newRowcol.row) {
        newRowcol.row.grid.api.cellNav
            .scrollToFocus(newRowcol.row.entity, 
                            newRowcol.row.grid.options.columnDefs[1]);
        }
    });
```

UPDATE: Here is my columnDefs:

```
 $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
 {
    name: 'itemCode',
    displayName: 'Part #',
    editableCellTemplate: $scope.itemCodeEditableTemplate,
    width: 150,
    cellTooltip: function (row, col) {
        return row.entity.itemCode
    }
},
{
    name: 'quantity', displayName: 'Qty', type: 'number', width: 60, 
    cellTooltip: function (row, col) {
      return row.entity.quantity
    }
}
]
```

Comment: I believe this is a bug with angular-ui-grid. When I raised it as a bug, it was  closed unfixed and with no details on a workaround. See https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/4812 and my SO post at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33991169/scrolltofocus-to-cell-with-enablecelleditonfocus-true-does-not-make-the-cell-edi

Comment: I have a workaround that worked for my case of wanting to jump to a field on the next line when tabbing past a certain cell with a certain value, however I realised it would not work for your case where you are using the down key to move. Basically, it involved creating fake spacer columns with enableCellEdit:false within the column definitions. If you could ask your users to tab between cells, post your column definitions and I can share the workaround as a possible answer.

Comment: OK. Thanks for your response. I am going to try https://www.ag-grid.com/ and see how that goes as I already have a work around for UI-Grid for typeahead etc. The way it is going I am going to end up with work arounds everywhere. If ag-grid doesn't work out, then I will ask you about your workaround

Comment: ok I am not too sure about ag-grid. It doesn't have add/remove rows (without refreshing the grid) and I am not sure if it has listeners for cell navigation events because I see an open issue for it on GitHub. I have updated my question to include the column defs. Can you show me your workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented above, I believe this is a bug in angular-ui-grid. My workaround is as follows...

The problem is using `scrollToFocus()` to go to another line, but your normal keyboard operation (tab, down arrow etc) would have taken you to a column that has `enableCellEdit: true`. So one workaround is to have the column AFTER where you are calling `scrollToFocus()` from be set with `enableCellEdit: false`.

It's ugly, but I created a "spacer" column after every column that could possibly be tabbed from.

```
{ name: 'itemCode', displayName: 'part #' },
{ name: 'quantity', displayName: 'qty' },
{ name: '_spacer1', displayName: '', width: '0%', minWidth: 1, maxWidth: 1, enableCellEdit: false },
{ name: 'someOtherColumn', displayName: 'something'},
```

So, in my case I wanted to catch a tab from "quantity" to "someOtherColumn" and if the value of row.entity.quantity was 0 (for example), then I would call `scrollToFocus()` to the next line. Because the normal next cell for tabbing had `enableCellEdit: false` it would work.

Now for your case, I am not sure it helps, because you are working with down arrow presses, which means you are not changing column with the normal keyboard operation. But perhaps it gives you an idea. (In addition, if your users would tab instead of down arrow, then you can use the workaround, or possibly not even need it, depending on which other columns you have.)

*I think a better idea might be to re-open my bug (linked in comments above) and say you are also having the problem and see if you can get a straight answer on what the real fix should be! (I'd love to see it.)*